# Why can't I create a pipe from this curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

[image] I have created a bezier curve and small circle. I want that circle take the shape of bezier curve so that the curve becomes a pipe. In the gif you will notice that its becoming flat, not like a pipe.
What is wrong with my settings?
Blend file [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this setup to work, your circle has to lay flat on Z axis.Like this:
[image]

And it has to have this rotation applied, so you can rotate it in object mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and choose Rotation or rotate it in edit mode. It will have exactly the same effect.

Comment: It work. But before it was also on the z axis but was not flat. May i know how it works little in details. Thanks

Comment: It basically works like you would draw bevel shape in 2d from top view in local space. So if it lays flat, it makes full, nice circle.If you rotate it a little, form the top view it makes an ellipse and so the bevel shape looks like.In local space means in this example Edit mode space and in general, it's set of coordinates in relation to the object own pivot point unlike world space, which is set of coordinates in relation to world center.